# What would be the best combination to clean polyurethane

Tags: polymers, cleaning

I am struggling to find the best composition to clean old golf balls and make them white again.
The balls are made out of different types of coating, e.g. polyurethane or an isomer.

I have found hydrogen peroxide to be so far a good candidate.
I cover the balls in hydrogen peroxide and expose them to UV light.
What I'm trying to figure out is how to find a good process or accelerator to the compound.

For example, should the balls only be soaked for 10 seconds or do they have to be in for 5 hours due to the material?

Would any other item (e.g. bleach or oxi washing powder) add to the cleaning power of hydrogen peroxide?

Any insights on a chemical level of what should be the best process forward or suggestion on how to evaluate my methods?

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right path. As for the exact procedure, I suspect one might need to play around with different conditions to find the optimal one. Still, a good question regarding underlying chemistry.